# systemd: how to make sure a service is started only after another service is up and running

Tags: startup, systemd, services

On a Ubuntu 20.04.2 TLS server, I have a need to start a service after another one has fully started up. Specifically, the `openvpn-server` service creates a `tun0` interface with the IP address 10.87.0.1 to which the `rinetd` service then binds. So the `rinetd` service should only be started *after* the `openvpn-server` service has created that interface.

`rinetd` comes with a sysvinit service script `/etc/init.d/rinetd` saying:

```
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
```

This causes `rinetd` to be started during system startup *before* `openvpn-server` has created the interface. It then emits the log message:

```
rinetd[792]: couldn't bind to address 10.87.0.1 port 873 (Cannot assign requested address)
```

and does not accept connections until I manually restart it with `sudo systemctl restart rinetd`, after which it then runs just fine.

According to `sudo systemctl status` the `openvpn` server process is run by a systemd service named `openvpn-server@server.service`.
Extending the `Required-Start` line in `/etc/init.d/rinetd` to say:

```
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog openvpn-server@server
```

is duly translated by `systemd-sysv-generator` to an additional line

```
After=openvpn-server@server.service
```

in `/run/systemd/generator.late/rinetd.service`.
But systemd ignores that. `rinetd` still shows the same log message and malfunction, proving that it is still started before `openvpn-server` is up.

How can I get systemd to reliably start the `rinetd` service only *after* the `openvpn-server` service has done its part and created the interface?

Comment: Maybe openvpn option `--up`, `--down`, `--restart` is better suited.

Comment: If you're trying to suggest starting the `rinetd` daemon from OpenVPN via an "up" command, please note that I'm talking about an OpenVPN *server*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we first take systemd, I think it's better if you address the interface directly. Devices in the dev and sysfs tree are exposed to systemd and can be used to make dependencies to other *units*.

Start by masking the original startup script.

```
systemctl mask --now rinetd.service
```

With an *instantiated* .service, e.g., `rinetd-daemon@.service`, you can start one or several instances if needed, if we were, to have more than one device (provided rinetd can bind to several interfaces).

```
[Unit]
Description=Rinetd connection forwarding service (%I)
  After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
BindsTo=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rinetd
PIDFile=/var/run/rinetd.pid
ExecReload=kill -HUP $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
```

You can then instantiate the service together with a device name:

```
systemctl enable --now rinetd-daemon@tun0.service
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I took the liberty of editing your answer to reflect that the service in my case is `rinetd`, not `ridentd`, but that doesn't diminish your merit.

Comment: nice... I will fill in some info about openvpn script hooks...

Answer (score 0):

The new `.service` file probably needs

```
[Unit]
After=openvpn-server@server.service
Requires=openvpn-server@server.service
```

The options can be confusing, but there are a ton of other resources that cover similar ground.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593242/systemd-using-both-after-and-requires
- https://serverfault.com/questions/812584/in-systemd-whats-the-difference-between-after-and-requires
- https://superuser.com/questions/1582738/after-doesnt-work-with-devices-in-systemd
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388586/systemd-requires-vs-wants
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files
- https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-unit-dependencies-and-order/

Comment: The answer lacks an essential part: how do I get systemd-sysv-generator to include those options when it creates the service file?

Comment: Also, the resources you list all seem to emphasize that `Requires=` does *not* affect execution order. So I'm curious if adding it (once I found a means to do so) will fix the issue.